# Mask editing for Pages

Tags: graphics, pages, text-editor

When trying to edit the mask, I am stuck with this blue dot that only rounds the corners of the mask and I can't get rid of it. How do I go about editing the mask borders?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce your problem here. Is it present anytime you try to edit a mask? Is it unique to a particular photo or document? Can you edit your answer and provide a (partial) screen shot so we can see what you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

You should also see the white squares defining the borders of the mask. Those are the handles for resizing borders. (It's also possible to select the picture behind the mask, in which case the handles surround the picture itself.)

Pixelcorps has a terrific MacBreak Work video [tutorial on masks](http://www.pixelcorps.tv/macbreak_work011) in iWork '09.

Comment: i can see them but they are little grey, and like deactivated so you cant really pick them. thats my problem.